# Is there any method that truncates part of a string until the first number is encountered in C#?

Tags: c#, string, texttrimming

I would like to know whether there is any method in C# that takes out all the content of a **string** until the first number is encountered. Example:

```
string myString = "USD3,000";
myString = SomeMethod(myString, [someparameters]);
myString -> "3,000"
```

Comment: Cheat sheet: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx and Quick Regex tester: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not inbuilt, but you could just use either a regex, or `IndexOfAny`:

```
static void Main()
{
    string myString = "USD3,000";
    var match = Regex.Match(myString, @"[0-9].*");
    if(match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    }
}
```

or

```
static readonly char[] numbers = "0123456789".ToCharArray();
static void Main()
{
    string myString = "USD3,000";
    int i = myString.IndexOfAny(numbers);
    if (i >= 0)
    {
        string s = myString.Substring(i);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marc that regex would return a match for for instance USD3a000 would be 3a000

Comment: @Oskar: that's exactly what the question is asking: "method that takes out all the content of a string until the first number is encountered" => get first number and match all the rest

Comment: @Paolo That's true. I just assumed that he wanted the first number

Comment: @Marc As I stated above, I misread his question. Figured he only wanted to get the numbers

Comment: Improvement? `Regex.Match(myString, @"\d[\d\.,]*");`

Comment: @ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ My regex was [\d\.,\s]+ which would match every delimiter as well

Comment: Not sure whitespace would form part of a valid number? Would also allow a number to start with period or comma.

Comment: @Oskar: the match fails if it does not encounter any of those carachters?

Comment: @ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ Sometime people write .3 as 0.3. Also, sometime it is valid to write "3 000 000"

Comment: @Oskar: the numbers I am dealing with are pretty standard. They use comma(,) for thousands and dot(.) for decimals.

Comment: @ʞɔɐɯɹoↃɔW sǝɯɐſ - the choice of[0-9] was deliberate, but it really comes down to what the OP defines as "a number" in the context. The first version I posted used `\d`, but that is a superset of "numbers", depending on interpretation

Comment: @Marc Gravell - Good point, `\d` includes all these characters, among others: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm Must try int.Parse() on some of those.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any built-in string methods to do that. However you can tweak the code given in the below post and modify it to achieve what you want:

[What is the most efficient way in C# to determine if a string starts with a number and then get all following numbers up until the first non-numeric character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499655/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-in-c-to-determine-if-a-string-starts-with-a-numbe)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Regular Expressions.

```
string myString = "USD3,000";
Regex reg = new Regex("[A-Za-z]");
myString = reg.Replace(myString, "");
```

Comment: Regex.Match is more suitable here

Comment: thanks but it works just if there are letters. It does not work with special charachters

Comment: @"[^\d]*" would be a more suitable regex

Answer (score 0):

```
    string str = "ddd3,000.00ss";

    string stripped = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3},(\d{3},)*\d{3}(\.\d{1,3})?|\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})?).*").Match(str).Value;

    Console.WriteLine(stripped);
```

Output:

```
3,000.00ss
```

Should match decimal and integer number with or without thousand separators and with or without maximum of 3 decimal places.

Comment: yes and it fails on "b2b_index_3,000.00ss" like the others giving "2b_index_3,000.00ss", I should  revise it a bit... unfortunately there is no easy method to avoid that... but probably noone tried this scenario, yet the answer is accepted...